# Connect with google plus button

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have implemented Connect with Google plus on a website. It is working fine except the following case: Consider I have logged in to Google account and then I visit my website I can see the popup from Google which is according to the snipped screen shot as below
[image]

I don't want this popup to be visible ever. Any

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this problem is by creating a simple JavaScript code and putting it in your pages. If the problem occurs on all pages, create a master file {name}.js and import it on all relevant pages. Right click on the bar, and choose "Inspect Element". Note down the div id/class name and cancel the inspect element dialog. Next, create a JS script, which states onLoad, the div box in concern will not be displayed.